# On Xamarin Studio iOS, cannot archive for publishing, Configuration doesn't target a device

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

In Xamarin Studio when clicking archive for publishing an error appears:

Configuration doesn't target a device

Your configuration doesn't target a valid iOS device.

Please select a device from the drop-down menu before archiving.

---

A device is selected in the drop-down, in the development configuration it will run on the device.

The distribution provisioning profile is also selected and present on the device. I have previously gone through and recreated all the distribution and development profiles again and the problem still persisted.

How can this be fixed any suggestions are welcome.

XCODE : version 8.2.1
Xamarin Studio Community: version 6.2

Comment: When you say "A device is selected" you mean a real device or a simulator? Make sure you select a real device to create the Archive.

Comment: Yes a real device is selected. If I'm using the development profile it will run on the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so I managed to fix this situation for me. Although a device was selected in the drop down the platform that my solution was trying to target was Any CPU and I believe this was causing the issue.

To fix this I created a new project, opened the .csproj file and selected all of the property groups and replaced the property groups in the original project with these.

At this point it was just a cases of ensuring all configurations matched up and the project could once again be archived.

Hope this helps anyone who encounters a similar problem.

Comment: I created a new blank project and it also did not archive, so I do not think copying the property groups would make a difference.